# With tikz and pgfplots, how can I control the mark of the points independently of "style" of the plot line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Please consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}% ,compat=1.18
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,magnification=6,connect spies,densely dotted}]
        \pgfplotsset{scale only axis,xmin=1.8, xmax=5}
        \begin{axis}[axis y line*=left,ymin=120, ymax=150,]
            \addplot[thick,dashed,smooth,mark=+,darkgray]
                coordinates{
                    (1.897222, 144)
                    (2.372222, 135)
                    (2.537500, 138)
                    (2.906250, 135)
                    (3.388889, 147)
                    (3.878472, 122)
                    (4.396528, 136)
                    (4.963889, 130)
                };
            \addplot[thick,smooth,mark=*,darkgray]
                coordinates{
                    (1.99, 123)
                    (2.2, 145)
                    (2.75, 134)
                    (3.25, 130)
                    (3.4, 137)
                    (3.8, 128)
                    (4.5, 146)
                    (4.9, 121)
                };
            \coordinate (spyone) at (axis cs:3.4,147);
            \coordinate (spytwo) at (axis cs:4.4,136);
            \coordinate (glassone) at (axis cs:3,125);
            \coordinate (glasstwo) at (axis cs:4.5,125);
        \end{axis}
        \spy[darkgray,size=3cm] on (spyone) in node[fill=white] at (glassone);
        \spy[darkgray,size=3cm] on (spytwo) in node[fill=white] at (glasstwo);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It yields the following (approximate, because the below is a pixel graphic and downscaled) output:

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

The two spies show the marks on the dashed (`thick,dashed,smooth,mark=+,darkgray`) line. A similar result can be "achieved" by setting `mark=x` instead.

Either way, the issue is that the drawing of the mark inherits the dashed style of the line.

**Question:** How can I use a solid style for drawing the marks, while retaining the line style as is?

PS: solid plots, like the second one, don't have the issue with. Neither with `mark=*` nor with `mark=x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: I have added `mark options=solid` to the `addplot` options

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}% ,compat=1.18
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,magnification=6,connect spies,densely dotted}]
        \pgfplotsset{scale only axis,xmin=1.8, xmax=5}
        \begin{axis}[axis y line*=left,ymin=120, ymax=150,]
            \addplot[thick,dashed,smooth,mark=+,darkgray, mark options=solid]
                coordinates{
                    (1.897222, 144)
                    (2.372222, 135)
                    (2.537500, 138)
                    (2.906250, 135)
                    (3.388889, 147)
                    (3.878472, 122)
                    (4.396528, 136)
                    (4.963889, 130)
                };
            \addplot[thick,smooth,mark=*,darkgray]
                coordinates{
                    (1.99, 123)
                    (2.2, 145)
                    (2.75, 134)
                    (3.25, 130)
                    (3.4, 137)
                    (3.8, 128)
                    (4.5, 146)
                    (4.9, 121)
                };
            \coordinate (spyone) at (axis cs:3.4,147);
            \coordinate (spytwo) at (axis cs:4.4,136);
            \coordinate (glassone) at (axis cs:3,125);
            \coordinate (glasstwo) at (axis cs:4.5,125);
        \end{axis}
        \spy[darkgray,size=3cm] on (spyone) in node[fill=white] at (glassone);
        \spy[darkgray,size=3cm] on (spytwo) in node[fill=white] at (glasstwo);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also you might play around with the `dash phase` option to shift the `+` marks if you would like.